# CSS issue when using ASP.NET Validation Control

Tags: asp.net, forms, validation

I'm using an ASP.NET Validation control and when there is an error, for some reason, some CSS are ignored. Using Firebug or IE Developer Tools I would have to reapply the styles in order to get it to where it was.

Any ideas why this glitch happens?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved, it appears that this was wrapped in a RadAjaxPanel and therefore you must add the CSS links in the header inorder for it to be rendered/applied.